# Variables won't pass with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to preface this by saying am new to jquery so please be gentle.
My problem is that I need to get some form variables from an html page to a php page. I tried the following but it won't work. Am quite befuddled. Please Help.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit', function() {

      var value = $('#N_cmd').val();
      var value1 = $('#N_clt').val();

      var value3 = $('#zone').val();
      $.post('process.php', {
        value: value,
        value1: value1,

        value3: value3
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
</script>


<script>
  function viewData() {
    $.ajax({

      url: 'process.php',

    }).done(function(data) {
      $('tbody').html(data)
      tableData()
      $('#example-table').dataTable()

    })

  }

  function tableData() {

    $('#example-table').Tabledit({
      url: 'process.php',
      eventType: 'dblclick',
      editButton: true,
      deleteButton: true,
      columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [
          [1, 'name'],
          [2, 'Firstname'],
          [3, 'age']
        ]
      },

      onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        viewData()
      },
      onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      },

      onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
        console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
        console.log(action);
        console.log(serialize);

      }
    });




  }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="viewData()">

  <div class="container">
        <form class='form-horizontal' id="lets_search"  action="" role='form'>




              <input class='form-control' name='N_cmd' id='N_cmd' placeholder='N° commande' type='text'>

              <select class='form-control' id='zone'>


                    <option> </option>
                    <option value="CENTRE">CENTRE</option>
                    <option value="NORD">NORD</option>
                    <option value="SUD">SUD</option>
                  </select>


                  <input class='form-control' name='id_division' id='id_division' placeholder='Division' type='text'>


            <button type="submit" id="send" name="send">Chercher</button>





    </form>

    <table id="example-table" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', '', 'demo');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo json_encode(array('mysqli' => 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()));
  exit;
}

if  (isset($_POST['value'],$_POST['value1'],$_POST['value3'])) {
echo $_POST['value'];
exit;}
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Yes, I've checked but there are no errors displayed!

Comment: Place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. See if the array is getting what you would expect.

Comment: what does "Won't work" mean? What is it not doing that you expected it to do? Currently you're posting data to the server and ignoring the response.

Comment: when I try echo $_POST['value']; in process.php just to check if this variable has the data i submitted in my form nothing happens.

Comment: .bind was deprecated by jQuery, and replaced about 6 years ago. Please use .on instead. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `#N_clt1` element in the HTML, but you are pulling a value from it with `var value1 = $('#N_clt').val();`.

Try `var value1 = $('#id_division').val();`

When they try to pull `value1` with the code above, they will get `undefined`. `$.post` will filter `undefined` values out of the request. Therefore, he only posts `value` and `value3` to the PHP script.

[image]

The PHP script checks for `value`, `value1`, and `value3`. Since `value1` will not be sent, he will see nothing. Tada.

---

Something that was also brought out in the comments of your post was that you don't do anything once you've posted the values. You only call `$.post`, but there is nothing actually done with what is returned by that post.

Well, you could reuse your `viewData` function like so:

```
$.post('process.php', {
    value: value,
    value1: value1,
    value3: value3
  }).done(function(data){
     viewData();
  });
```

That's the quickest way for it to work. But it calls `process.php` unnecessarily, eww! Let's make it a little better:

```
 $.post('process.php', {
    value: value,
    value1: value1,
    value3: value3
  }).done(function(data){
     $('tbody').html(data)
     tableData()
     $('#example-table').dataTable()
  });
```

Now it does the same thing as `viewData` does, and we only need to request `process.php` once. The key is: **you must do something with the response of the $.post to `process.php`**.

Homework: we have to repeat the same code in the `$.post`'s `done` callback as we do in `viewData()`. Abstract that into a separate function, so both `viewData()` and the callback can use the same code without having to repeat.

Comment: yes sorry I deleted some unecessary code snippets and I left that one there. But it still won't work since am only using echo on var value .

Comment: @SaraPaxton here's a better question: What are you expecting to see when you press the "Chercher" button?

Comment: When I press it I would like to display the searched info in my table but since there seems to be a problem with my code I only used echo to check the variables whether or not they have the data I submitted in the form.

Comment: @SaraPaxton Ok I've updated my answer. See if that helps you at all. In your next questions, be sure to specifically state your intentions and what you'd like to see happen. Hope it helps!

Comment: I genuinely don't know what am doing wrong! It's not working. All I want to do is pass my form variables to process.php in order to use them for search queries. But I can't get it to work.